# How to call REST API in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I have 2 GAE. GAE1 has REST API (Tastypie without implementation of oauth authentication). GAE2 calls the REST API of GAE1.

If calling the API:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://___GAE1____.com/api_ws/api/v1/test/?format=json").read()
```

the returned result is sign-on page, not JSON result from GAE1.

How to perform authentication hosted by GAE? OAuth2 or API key?

I read https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

But could not figure out what is client secret, scope (my REST API or some google cloud API?)

Comment: I just want to add that the login user of GAE2 can't be used to authenticate REST API of GAE1.

Comment: Can someone give me details how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Getting same issue please give me solution if anyone have.